# vue-router url can't find when its revisite/reload in laravel project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

When i re hit the vue-router url its return 404 page not found.

I running it on laravel 5.8. in web.php file

I tried some of these but they don't work

```
Route::get('/{capture_all?}', 'HomeController@index')->where('capture_all', '[\/\w\.-]');

Route::get('/{vue_capture?}', 'HomeController@index')->where('vue_capture', '[\/\w\.-]');

Route::get('/{any}', 'HomeController@index')->where('any', '[\/\w\.-]');
```

the page will refreshed

Answer (score 0):

Consider a [fallback route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#fallback-routes):

```
Route::fallback('HomeController@index');
```

Any unknown route will be passed to this fallback route. Any known routes (like to your APIs) will remain untouched.